# Proving conserved quantities of $N$-vortices using Hamiltonian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, hamiltonian, vortex

I'm trying to prove the conserved quantities for $N$-vortices but having a difficult time doing so. I know it's something to do with Noether's theorem but not sure how to go about it. The Hamiltonian is
$$
H = \frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{\beta \neq \alpha}^N\Gamma_{\alpha}\Gamma_{\beta}logl_{\alpha\beta}
$$
Where l is the distance between vortices. I need to use the fact that H is translational invariant and rotational invariant which I can show. The translational invariance gives

$$
X = \sum_{\alpha}^N\Gamma_{\alpha}z_{\alpha}
$$

and the rotational invariance should give

$$
I = \sum_{\alpha}^N\Gamma_{\alpha}|z_{\alpha}|^2
$$

But again, I'm not sure how to show that X and I are conserved. Not necessarily looking a solution but just to point me in the right direction further than just 'use Noether's theorem'. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no explicit time dependence, the Heisenberg equation of motion relates the time derivative of an operator to its commutator with the Hamiltonian as follows:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mathcal{O} = \frac{i}{\hbar} [H,\mathcal{O}]$$
From this we see that, in such cases, an operator that commutes with the Hamiltonian corresponds to a conserved quantity. The objects $\Gamma$ in your system probably come with some (anti)commutation relations, which you could exploit to test if $X$ and $I$ are conserved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have used this relation prior in a separate proof using the Poisson bracket I believe. So you are saying that with this relationship proposed, using invariance to translations and such should give the bracket = 0?

Comment: Yes, if you're dealing with a classical system, the corresponding result holds at the level of Poisson brackets. See, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_quantity#Hamiltonian_mechanics